# Find an $f:\Bbb{R}\rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ such that $f(x+2)-f(x)=x^2+2x+4$ holds for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$ and $f(x)=x^2$ for all $x\in [0,2)$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Find a function $f:\Bbb{R}\rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ such that

1. $f(x+2)-f(x)=x^2+2x+4$ for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$.
2. $f(x)=x^2$ for all $x\in [0,2)$.

Please give a hint for the problem. I have not getting the way to proceed.

Comment: Hint : what can you say about $f$ on $[2,4)$ ?

Comment: $f(2)=4$, correct?

Comment: Yes! But you can actually find the entire interval $[2,4)$ at once, in terms of $x$.

Comment: If $x \in [0,2)$ then $x+2 \in [2,4)$ and $f(x+2)-f(x) = f(x+2)-x^2$.

Answer (score 3):

This is a linear inhomogeneous problem. The general solution of
$$f(x+2)-f(x)=x^2+2x+4\tag{1}$$
can be found by the hom+part procedure: Find the general solution $f_{\rm hom}$ of the homogenized equation
$$f(x+2)-f(x)=0\ ,\tag{2}$$
and add to it a "particular" solution of $(1)$ that you have found "somehow".

The general solution of $(2)$ is obvious: $f_{\rm hom}$ can be any periodic function of period $2$. For $(1)$ we *guess* a solution of the form
$$f_{\rm part}(x):=ax^3+bx^2+ cx+ d\ ,$$
and try to adjust the coefficients such that $(1)$ is fulfilled. It turns out that
$$f_{\rm part}(x):={x^3\over6}+{4x\over3}$$
does the trick. The general solution of $(1)$ then is
$$f(x)=f_{\rm hom}(x)+{x^3\over6}+{4x\over3}\qquad(-\infty<x<\infty)\ .\tag{3}$$
Any $f$ of the form $(3)$ with an arbitrary $2$-periodic $f_{\rm hom}$ fulfills condition 1. of your question. But there is also condition 2., and this condition will determine $f_{\rm hom}$. We  have to make sure that
$$f(x)=f_{\rm hom}(x)+{x^3\over6}+{4x\over3}=x^2\qquad(0\leq x<2)\ .$$
This leads to the condition
$$f_{\rm hom}(x)=x^2-{x^3\over6}-{4x\over3}=-{1\over6}x(x-2)(x-4)\qquad(0\leq x<2)\ .\tag{4}$$
This refers only to the $x$-interval $[0,2[\>$. But $(4)$
automatically fixes $f_{\rm hom}$ as a  function on *all* of ${\mathbb R}$, since $f_{\rm hom}$ has to be periodic with period $2$.

We can now consider $(3)$ as final solution of the problem, whereby $f_{\rm hom}:\>{\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}$ is the *periodized* function given on the RHS of $(4)$ for $0\leq x<2$. You could write
$$f_{\rm hom}(x):=-{1\over6}t(t-2)(t-4)\biggr|_{t:=x-2\lfloor x/2\rfloor}\qquad(-\infty<x<\infty)\ .$$
[image]

Comment: Ok. Would you please explain how $f_{\rm hom}$ is periodic???

Comment: would you please explain the line "   But $(4)$ 
fixes $f_{\rm hom}$ as a (by coincidence) continuous function on all of ${\mathbb R}$, since $f_{\rm hom}$ has to be periodic with period $2$. "